# create a profile page with django

Tags: python, django, hash, change-password

I created a profile page with django to let users change their information that I gave in sing up form . (such as name, email, password)

I have two problem on password field :

1 - when user insert a password in text field, it's submitted in raw format, and I need django user's table format

```
<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>
```

my view for profile page :

```
def user_profile(request):
    current_user = request.user
    form = UserProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=current_user)
    if request.POST:
        if form.is_valid():
             # pwd = form.cleaned_data['password']
             # form_obj = form.save(commit=False)
             # form_obj.password = make_password(pwd)
             form.save()
             message = "saved successfully"
             return render(request, 'Profile.html', {'form':form, 'message':message}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    return render_to_response('Profile.html', {
        'form': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

as you can see in comments, I used make_password function to hash password and it works fine BUT after submitting page, user can't go to other pages and need re-login ... why ?!

2 - when the profile page shows to user, it's filled with current informations in database, and password is also in the above format (hash)
and if user submit the form, without any change in password field, it's password changed (it sends hash one and hash it again !)

how can I solve this problems and make a simple working profile page in django ? (I really don't like it's own admin panel ! it doesn't look nice !)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Changing a user’s password will log out all their sessions if the SessionAuthenticationMiddleware is enabled.

So you have to use `update_session_auth_hash(request, user)`

For more info, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change

Regarding the password field being pre-populated: you should set the field as a `passwordInput` which, by default, is not pre-populated, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.PasswordInput

Comment: it works ! thanks a lot
and how about the second problem ?

Comment: in this case user should enter his password each time (because if he left it blank he will get an error and if he just enter submit, his password changes to something long !)

Comment: I talk about the second problem in the last part of my answer, basically you need to modify your form...

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your comment... Yes I understand what you mean, I think you should update all fields except password, and update password only if not empty... You can do that in your view

Comment: Also, you might want to have two fields, and ask the user to type the new password twice... It will help preventing unwanted typing errors by the user...

Comment: One las tip... Usually I prefer having the update password functionality in a separate form... So what I usually do is I have a profile form which doesn't have a password field at all...

Comment: but password field is required , user can't leave it empty

Comment: You can decide which fields are required in a form, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#required